# x label in ggplot to be in ascending order

Tags: r

I want to plot following dataframe with week vs amount starting with week7 in x -axis.

```
df <- data.frame(week = c("w7","w8","w9","w10","w11","w12"),
             amount = c(34,56,78,90,12,23),
             outlier = c(0,0,0,1,0,0))

 week amount outlier
 w7     34       0
 w8     56       0
 w9     78       0
 w10    90       1
 w11    12       0
 w12    23       0
```

But the plot starts with w10.
How to ensure that it starts with w7.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = week, y = amount, col = outlier)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90))
```

Comment: Use `aes(x = factor(week, levels=unqiue(week), ...)` or `aes(x=forcats::fct_inorder(week), ...)`

Comment: `df$week <- factor(df$week, df$week)`

Comment: @MrFlick Throwing error. Can you please elaborate

Comment: The existing duplicate goes into more detail. You need to format your x variable as a factor with levels in the correct order. You can either modify your data or change it in the aes()